# load link from left bar to right div

Tags: html, css

Can someone help me with this problem

check site -> [Link](https://food-line.net/~foodline/restomulti/linkit/sivu/)

The links on the left div must be opened on the right gray div

but when i click on the links nothing happend, only the first link "etusivu" opens the file "etu.html" on the footer :/

my css & html codes below:

```css
body, html{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    position:relative;
    height:100%
}

.header {
    width:100%;
    height: 128px;
    background: #F32C2D;
    padding:10px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.footer{
    width:100%;
    height: 100px;
    background:#ccc;
    padding:10px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.content {
    background:#eee;
    width:100%;
    padding:10px;
    height:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding:10px;
}

.left{
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    background: #CE1212;
    height:100%;
}

.right{
    width: auto;
    background:#aaa;
    height:100%;
}

.logoimg {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  margin-left: 2%;
}

.titletext {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: white;
}

.vertical-menu {
  width: 200px; /* Set a width if you like */
}

.vertical-menu a {
  background-color: #eee; /* Grey background color */
  color: black; /* Black text color */
  display: block; /* Make the links appear below each other */
  padding: 12px; /* Add some padding */
  text-decoration: none; /* Remove underline from links */
}

.vertical-menu a:hover {
  background-color: #ccc; /* Dark grey background on mouse-over */
}

.vertical-menu a.active {
  background-color: #F32C2D; /* Add a green color to the "active/current" link */
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <img class="logoimg" src="logo.png" alt="Food-Line" height="125" width="125">
    <h1 class="titletext">Food-Line Tuki</h1>
    <h3 class="titletext">Autamme mielellämme</h3>
</div>

<div class="content">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="vertical-menu">
       <a href="etu.html" class="active" target="right">Etusivu</a>
       <a href="#">Käyttö- & toimitusehdot</a>
       <a href="maksaminen.html" target="right">Maksaminen</a>
       <a href="#">Mobiilisovellus</a>
       <a href="#">Tilaaminen</a>
       <a href="#">Ota Yhteyttä</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right" id="right">
      <iframe name="right" src="" width="100%"
        height="100%" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
        <p>testi testi testi</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
    footer content
</div>
</body>
```

any one have any ideas ?

again i want that when i click some link on the left tha target html file of the link must be opened on the right gray div

Comment: are you trying to make tabs?

Comment: `<a href="#">` is link to nothing,give it a path.

Comment: What you mean tabs ?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_vertical_tabs.asp

Comment: i know <a href="#"> is no link to any where but i want to know what i have to do to open for example <a href="rules.html"> Rules </a> on the right side div

Comment: It looks like it's working as expected. You click a link and it opens an iframe with the content, and the site's URL does not change. What did you want to happen?

Comment: @tshimksu yes it now works !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your iframe and div have the same name and are probably clashing try rename the iframe

If you would like your iframe to autoload etu.html try this:

```
<iframe name="right" src="etu.html" width="100%">
```

Also make all link tags target the **iframe** and not the right div you done it correct with etu.html just fix the rest

Comment: Hi mate thnx for answer. plz check -> https://food-line.net/~foodline/restomulti/linkit/sivu/  and from the left select Etusivu and Maksaminen links see what it looks like on the right ? now its loading the target file on the right but looks not good

Comment: Try adding frameborder="0" to iframe tag it should get rid of the border for you

Comment: Also go to CSS and add Padding: 0px; to your right div i wouldn't normally do this just because you have an iframe in the div the iframe has its own padding

Comment: done. have u any idea for the left menu "active" coloring not working cna u plz chck css code for  ->  .vertical-menu a.active

Comment: .vertical-menu a.active { should be .vertical-menu a:active { you used a dot instead of colon

Comment: Only other way I can think would be PHP here's a tutorial I found for you [link](https://alistapart.com/article/keepingcurrent)